# How to grade scores in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to grade some scores according to highest average obtained..
**Here's my scripts**

```
$scores_AND_ID = 'M2377O=100,M2727B=100,M5821K=100,M7492F=97.75,M7973O=96,M3487I=94,M7969O=93.13,M1452V=92.5,M4653O=92.38,M4158J=92.25,M2881A=89.38,M6112S=28.63,';
    $out_score = chop($scores_AND_ID, ',');
    $rr2 = explode(",", $out_score);


    $array_un = array_unique($rr2);
    foreach ($array_un as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == "") {
            continue;
        }


        $postion = positionNumbers($key);//1st,2nd,3rd function
        $sec = explode("=", $value);
        rsort($sec);
        $stdntID = $sec[0]; //Student number
        $stdntAV = $sec[1]; //Student Average

        mysql_query("UPDATE score_table SET grade='$postion' WHERE avg='$stdntAV' ");

    }
```

I'm using foreach key to assign grade position but isn't working properly.
 Here's my result [image: Current rsult]

Here's what I need to achieve.

```
    1. 100---1st
    2. 100---1st
    3. 100---1st
    4. 98---4th
    5. 89.5--5th
    6. 89---6th
    7. 89---6th
    8. 80---8th
```

Thanks Guys

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Comment: @Dharman I'm very sure about the deprecated mysql however this's just a simple illustration to my question thank you.

Comment: Show positionNumbers($key) code

Comment: @Dharman to be fair, you're making an assumption about being vulnerable to SQL injection here.

Answer (score 0):

You should not update your records if grade is already set. If you print your query instead of executing it you will see that you set grade 1st, then you overwrite it with 2nd and then with 3rd.

Comment: Please can you post scripts it can also be of help to others...thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the code you want is this:

```
<?php

$scores_AND_ID = 'M7492F=97.75,M7973O=96,M3487I=94,M2377O=100,M2727B=100,M5821K=100,M7969O=93.13,M1452V=92.5,M4653O=92.38,M4158J=92.25,M2881A=89.38,M6112S=28.63,';

// Gets all of the entries from the source string
$scores_array = array_unique(array_filter(explode(',', $scores_AND_ID)));

// Sets up an associative array of values (student id => score)
$score_map = [];
foreach ($scores_array as $record) {
    [ $student_id, $score ] = explode('=', $record);

    $score_map[$student_id] = $score;
}

// Ensure values are sorted numerically descending
uasort($score_map, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a > $b) {
        return -1;
    }
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
});

// Gets the maximum value from the scores
$previous_score = max(array_values($score_map));

$rank = 1;
$incrementer = 0;
foreach ($score_map as $student => $score) {
    // If the score hasn't changed from it's previous value
    // we increment a counter instead of the rank
    if ($score == $previous_score) {
        $incrementer++;
    // Once it's changed, we update the rank based on the incrementer
    // and then reset the incrementer
    } else {
        $rank += $incrementer;
        $incrementer = 1;
    }

    $previous_score = $score;

    // Updating database is left as an exercise to the reader
}
```

Comment: please can you help me to fix those errors on the script? thank you.